# Stack Overflow answers to Documentation

Tags: discussion, feature-request, documentation, documentation-topics

I think in every documentation topics there should be a "Document it with an **answer of a question from Stack Overflow**" option. When i select i should be able to edit that answer and send it to documentation with source and writer.

Comment: I like this idea, credit to the originator even if they don't put it on Documentation themselves. I've already seen several copy/pastes without attribution(and without even any editing to make it more suitable as Documentation)